# Marking Activities with Priority "urgent" in another color

Tags: civicase, activity

In the CiviCRM system I work on, activities created for a specific case can have the priority "normal" or "urgent". This attribute is set by the user when creating the activity inside the CaseView. Internally, the "priority_id" of this activity is set to 1 == "urgent" or 2 == "normal".
Now, I want to mark the activities with priority "urgent" in another color when listed in the CaseView as well as in the Case Overview (Cases > My Cases). I started with the first task (changing the activity layout in the CaseView activity list).

I tried modifying the sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityToCase.tpl at line 23, added the following if-clause. This template is included in sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.tpl in line 259, which seemed like the correct place in the CaseView.tpl for the activities to appear. I added:

```
{if $form.priority_id == 1}
   <td class="label urgent">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.label}</td>
{elseif $form.priority_id == 2}
   <td class="label">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.label}</td>
{/if}
```

where before we only had:

```
<td class="label">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.label}</td>
```

When this didn't work, I tried to set an "urgent" class to the $form.file_on_case_activity_subject.html as well:

```
{if $form.priority_id == 1}
          <td class="label urgent">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.label}</td>
          <td class="urgent">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.html}<br />
            <span class="description">{ts}You can modify the activity subject before filing.{/ts}</span>
          </td>
        {elseif $form.priority_id == 2}
        <td class="label">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.label}</td>
          <td>{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.html}<br />
            <span class="description">{ts}You can modify the activity subject before filing.{/ts}</span>
          </td>
        {/if}
```

where before we only had:

```
<td class="label">{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.label}</td>
<td>{$form.file_on_case_activity_subject.html}<br />
            <span class="description">{ts}You can modify the activity subject before filing.{/ts}</span>
          </td>
```

As this didn't work either, I suppose I am modifying the wrong place. Any hint anyone?

Edit: I created an extension with the following code, but it doesn't work yet:

```
function mark_urgent_activities_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Case_Form_CaseView') {
    CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addStyle('#crm-container table.nestedActivitySelector tr.priority-urgent {background-color: orange;}');
  }
}
```

Edit2: Accessing the elements with priority-urgent class works in the css file, both as

```
.priority-urgent {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and

```
#crm-container table.nestedActivitySelector tr.priority-urgent {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

The (background / font) color doesn't work yet, but I suppose that's only because  element cannot have background color.

Comment: It worked when I tested it - but I didn't restrict to CRM_Case_Form_CaseView. The table is created by magic after the page loads so maybe there's a timing issue if you restrict the form. The background-color worked for me - maybe you have other customizations conflicting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, all you need to do is make an extension and call `CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addStyle()` in hook_buildForm as described at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets since activities with priority urgent already get class priority-urgent added to the `<tr>` element in the table that lists the activities.

e.g.
`CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addStyle('#crm-container table.nestedActivitySelector tr.priority-urgent {background-color: orange;}');`

The `#crm-container table.nestedActivitySelector` part is required because otherwise the more specific css target from core gets applied instead.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly activities with priority urgent get the class priority-urgent added to the <tr> element? And where does the more specific css target from core get applied?

Comment: `grep -r priority-urgent *` - says it's in CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php - line 1022 (I'm using 5.31/dev - line number might be slightly different in other versions.) Similarly the more specific css part is in css/civicrm.css.